# Run linux commands from windows in python script

Tags: python-2.7

How do you run linux commands on a remote linux server from a windows host using a python script. I am using Python 2.7.10 and I want to ssh into a remote linux machine and issue some basic commands all from the script which is executed on a windows host.

Comment: @ŁukaszR. that's awesome! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/). Example:

Install via pip:

> pip install paramiko

Code:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("ip address", username="user_name", password="password", port=1234)

ssh.exec_command('your command')
```

This will allow you to establish an SSH connection between your two machines and execute commands. You can read the output like this:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
lines = stdout.readlines()
errors = stderr.readlines()
for e in errors:
    print 'error', e

for l in lines:
    print 'line', l
```