# How to execute linux commands on Windows using python?

Tags: python, linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Context**:

I have been tasked with researching how to execute linux commands using python. Since I am on windows, I have to execute 'wsl' first to swtich to the ubuntu distro I downloaded from microsoft store. Note that I am not a python programmer but currently working as a java intern. Although the python project/script will be deployed on a linux machine right now this is the only way for me to test the program.

**Problem**:

The problem I am getting is that if I have an list of commands and I am trying to execute them one by one, for some reason at the end of every command a return carriage is being found because apparently in windows DOS uses carriage return and line feed ("\r\n") as a line ending whereas in linux uses just line feed ("\n").

This is the python script

```
import subprocess


   
commands=["ls -al ~","pwd"]

# Initialize the WSL process
process = subprocess.Popen("wsl", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True)
# Execute each command in WSL
for command in commands:
    process.stdin.write((command)+"\n")
    
# Close the stdin and wait for the process to complete
process.stdin.close()
process.wait()
# Read and print the response from WSL
output = process.stdout.read()
print("WSL:", output)
```

I tried stripping '\r' but it makes absolutely zero difference as if it doesn't understand what '\r' is.
Here is the output:

```
WSL: ls: cannot access '~'$'\r': No such file or directory
-bash: line 2: $'pwd\r': command not found
```

**Solution 1**
`write` converted `\n` to `\r\n`, try this :

```
import subprocess

commands=["ls -al ~","pwd"]

# Initialize the WSL process
process = subprocess.Popen("wsl", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True)
# Execute each command in WSL
with open(process.stdin.fileno(), mode='w', newline='') as f:
    for command in commands:
        f.write((command)+'\n')

# Close the stdin and wait for the process to complete
# process.stdin.close()
# process.wait()
# Read and print the response from WSL
output = process.stdout.read()
print("WSL:", output)
```

Update: Thanks for the solution but and I also figured out a solution myself. It works like a charm.
**Solution 2 by questioner**

```
import subprocess
import shlex

# Define a list of commands
commands = ["ls -al ~", "pwd", "pwd"]

# Initialize the WSL process and execute each command
for command in commands:
    command_list = shlex.split(command)
    #Remove the ['wsl'] if this script is ran in linux environment
    #Also I am assuming that the default shell is bash
    #If it's not then enter into bash mode(or anyother) by replacing 'wsl' with 'bash'

    result = subprocess.run(['wsl'] + command_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    print("WSL:", result.stdout)
```

Comment: Why are you passing `text=True` to `popen`?  Looks like that's the source of the extra CRs.

Comment: If you have WSL Ubuntu running, why not do everything under WSL? Then there's no need to open "wsl" separately.

Comment: Note that lots of Linux commands have near-enough equivalents in Python; you may have to do some extra steps to get similar output (but perhaps you don't even want that), like sorting or providing more details as in `ls -l`. It is a fairly odd thing to execute Linux commands through Python. my advice: for a simple set of commands, use a bash script; for a complicated set of commands, write a proper (Python) program

Comment: A much simpler solution is `for command in commands: print(subprocess.run(['wsl'] + shlex.split(command), text=True).stdout)` and get rid of the whole attempt to use `Popen`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run linux commands from windows in python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725229/run-linux-commands-from-windows-in-python-script)

Comment: Alternatively, `print(subprocess.run(['wsl'] input='\n'.join(commands), text=True).stdout)` but then you can't know which command produced which rows of output.

Comment: @9769953 that is true, I could install python and move the script to linux directory but still why would the /r not be removed when I try to. Also thanks for pointing out my stupidity.

Comment: I agree that the \\r is awkward, and likely happens somewhere between subprocess and Windows passing it on to the WSL. Perhaps you'd need to pass binary commands to process.stdin.write, not sure. But let us know if the duplicate helps you.